# Contentplaceholder for replacing attributes?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

The code below works but confuses Visual Studio. Are there alternative/better ways to accomplish this?

```
<body <asp:contentplaceholder id="BodyAttribute" runat="server"/>>
```

Comment: @IrishChieftain yes its have 2 ">" because hes like to add the content inside the body tag

Comment: @Aristos, gotcha :-) But I fail to see why someone would have a need to do this...

Comment: @IrishChieftain To render text **inside** the tag.

Comment: @Aristos, this is not very maintainable and obviously unsupported by VS. I think I have to agree with Dymitrii in that there has to be a better way to do whatever it is Curtis is trying to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

Other way

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="BodyAttribute" runat="server"><body></asp:contentplaceholder>
```

and on contentPlaceholder you type

```
<body attr="whatever">
```

If not place holder found, then the `<body>` is used.

Comment: Unfortunately this completely confuses the visual studio editor. Hmm I thought this was the best solution. Now I'm having second thoughts

Answer (score 1):

I don't think doing this is a good idea in general.

First of all, with `ContentPlaceHolder`s you can easily end-up with HTML with **newlines in `id`** attribute.

Secondly, the code will be a total **spaghetti**. You will not be able to maintain it.

Thirdly, there must be **a better way** of accomplishing what you need.

For example, if you need to change the `body id` for the CSS styling purpose, or using it in JavaScript you will be better of with creating a nested div for that.

Master:

```
<body>
  <!-- div wrapper for general styling purposes -->
  <div id="mainContentWrapper">
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="Maincontent" runat="server" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Page:

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="MainContent" runat="server">
  <!-- div wrapper for page specific styling -->
  <div id="pageSpecificIdForYourPuprose">
    Your content goes here
  </div>
</asp:content>
```

Which will give you very style-able HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="mainContentWrapper">
    <div id="pageSpecificIdForYourPuprose">
      Your content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would really try to avoid those WebForms tricky things to accomplish simple thing. Simple things can be done the simple way (pretty often at least).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do

```
<body id="body1" runat="server">
```

this page shows an example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzk7dby1(vs.71).aspx

the example is based off .net 1.1 but i've used something similar for .net 2.0